# Can´t export mesh after making Curves/Edges with solidfy to Cubes

Tags: export

I have Problems with exporting my Mesh to FBX after I solidified Lines, so that they became Cubes.

1. I load Streets from GIS in Blender
2. I Separated the Lines, so that every Line was one street
3. I made Faces out of the lines
4. On these Faces I applied the solidifier to make them to cubes

But now I can´t export them (blank)

Thank you for your help! [image: Here an Image]

Comment: pls upload file

Comment: Export as what? A _Solidify Modifier_ doesn't make a real mesh out of it, and a modifier cannot be exported. You first have to apply the modifier so that it generates a real mesh.

Comment: I solved the Problem.. It was a failure by importing the streets from GIS..

@GordonBrinkmann this is what I did